# How to avoid N + 1 problem finding collection in DB (using Criteria API) with pagination in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have an entity **A**, that has @OneToMany Collection<**B**> b. I want to get from DB **page** of collection A with theirs collections b. Using *Criteria*, I get N + 1 problem. Using *entity graph* or *JOIN FETCH* causes in-memory pagination. The only one solution that works - @BatchSize, but people say that it is a bad solution.
So I am asking what is the best way to solve this problem.

Stack: Java, Spring Boot, Hibernate